# Linux: kill with negative pid

Tags: c, linux, unix

From [SUSv4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html):

> If pid is negative, but not -1, sig shall be sent to all processes
>   (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group
>   ID is equal to the absolute value of pid, and for which the process
>   has permission to send a signal.

As I understand there can't be 2 or more processes with the same PID at any time. Why the spec says to all processes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The spec says to all processes **within the given group.** There can be multiple processes per group. The negative `id` identifies the group.

Answer (score 6):

**Process Group ID is different from Process ID.**

Assuming that the PID is known, PGID is

> Every process is member of a unique *process group*, identified by its *process group ID*.
> (When the process is created, it becomes a member of the process group of its parent.) By
> convention, the process group ID of a process group equals the process ID of the first
> member of the process group, called the *process group leader*. A process finds the ID of its
> process group using the system call `getpgrp()`, or, equivalently, `getpgid(0)`. One finds the
> process p using `getpgid(p)`.

[Source](http://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html#ss10.2)